# Resetting an IP Core FIFO in Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, fifo, modelsim

I'm using the builtin FIFO, in FWFT mode. I try resetting it for 9 clocks, then leave the reset line low at the beginning. There is a large gap before the first write enable rises.

Modelsim then complains that I have not reset the FIFO correctly when the write enable goes high. Yet I see the correct data coming in and out of the block. If I don't reset it, or I don't leave a gap between the reset and the first write enable, then I don't get correct data out. Why is this happening?

My only hunch is that I'm compiling and running modelsim using the `-nodebug` flag on the IP cores, but I can't remove it at the moment to test out my theory.

[image: Signals]

[image: Error Message]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Search the generated source code for the ASSERT that raises that error, and trace back from there. Basic sim debugging applies in generated IP too.

Comment: OK so I can find plenty of assert statements, but I couldn't find one that produces the text "must be observed" - even after a quick grep I can only see it appearing in the log file. What I find very strange about this though is you can see all input signals are held low and reset is held high for a considerable amount of time.

Comment: @BrianDrummond in fact the only thing I can find in there is this warning:

`// if (C_EN_SAFET_CKT == 1)
// assertion:the reset shud be atleast 3 cycles wide.`

and

`$display("WARNING:A write attempt has been made within the 7 clock cycles of reset de-assertion. This can lead to data discrepancy when safety circuit is enabled.");`

which doesn't count for me.

Comment: What's this // and $display stuff? looks like verilog, sorry I can,t help with that

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Simulation files for IP cores are now compiled in verilog, so you better get used to it. I'm coming from VHDL too - but I can't find anything to that string which should have been easy to find. Furthermore having read the guide on this IP core, I have done everything correctly in the reset according to the manual.